# SQL: Copy missing rows from one table to another based on primary key column only

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to copy missing rows from one table to another but only if the primary key field does not exist. Both tables have identical column names but I don't have the number of columns and their names and don't have the primary key column name so it could be "ID" or anything else. Let me explain with an example:

Table 1:

```
   column 1 (primary key) , Column 2 , Column 3 , ...
   1 , England , London , ...
   2 , France , Paris , ...
   3, Italy , Rome , ...
   4 , Germany , Berlin , ...
```

Table 2:

```
    column 1 (primary key) , Column 2 , Column 3 , ...
    1 , Whatever , Whatever , ...
    2 , Whatever , Whatever , ...
```

I want to copy row 3 and 4 into table 2 so the outcome will be:

Table 2:

```
    column 1 (primary key) , Column 2 , Column 3 , ...
    1 , Whatever , Whatever , ...
    2 , Whatever , Whatever , ...
    3 , Italy , Rome , ...
    4 , Germany , Berlin , ...
```

I have tried

```
   REPLACE INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
```

but this will replace the entire table i.e. Table 2 become exactly like Table 1

Comment: It sounds dubious that you don't know how your schema looks like. However you might get this information from the catalog ([`information_schema`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html)). Read the needed information from there and build your queries up on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into table2 ( col1, col2 . . . )
    select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, . . .
    from table1 t1
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the description I don't have info on the number of columns and their names

Comment: @Matty . . . If you don't know anything about the tables you are working with, well, you are not going to be able to do much with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore rows from `table1` with existing primary key in `table2` then simplest way is to use `INSERT IGNORE` syntax:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Note that a row is ignored and not inserted, if there is a duplicate in any UNIQUE KEY (not only PRIMARY).

Documentation: [INSERT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

> If you use the `IGNORE` modifier, errors that occur while executing the
>   `INSERT` statement are ignored. For example, without `IGNORE`, a row that
>   duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   `IGNORE`, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors
>   generate warnings instead.

Also note that the columns in both tables should be defined in the same order. Actually the tables should have the exactly same schema (same columns with the same data types, length, character sets and collations).